How to plot vectors of zonally averaged meridional-vertical wind circulation in a latitude-pressure cross-section in MATLAB
I have 3D matrices (longitude×latitude×plev) of U, V, and W components of wind. Since I want to plot latitude-pressure vertical cross section, I took average along the first dimension (i.e, longitude) for V and W components of wind. Also, initially, I had the plev data with 12 pressure levels. But, I created 91 interpolated pressure levels using the'meshgrid' command and interpolated the V and W components of wind data at each pressure level using the 'griddata' command, like in the following:
[X_LAT,Y_PLEV]=meshgrid(latitude,min(plev):10:max(plev));
V=griddata(latitude,plev,Vwind',X_LAT,Y_PLEV); 

But when I tried to plot the wind vectors along the latitude-pressure vertical cross-section using the 'quiversc' function, I got absurd vectors (see the figure attached).

But, previously, with the same 'quiversc' function, I got the correct wind vectors when I used U and V components of wind at the x-y plane for a particular pressure level. So, I think there is nothing wrong with the function. Maybe the code should be different this time as I am plotting latitude-pressure vertical cross section. My code for plotting was as follows:
contourf(X_LAT,Y_PLEV,W,40,'linecolor','none') ; 
set(gca,'YDir','reverse');
set(gca,'yscale','log')
hold on
q1=quiversc(X_LAT,Y_PLEV,V,W,'density',10,'MaxHeadSize',5,'AutoScale','on','color','k','LineWidth',1);
colormap(jet(50))
caxis([-2 2])
xlim([-7 1])
ylim([100 1000])
box on
set(gca,'YTick',(100:100:1000),'YTickLabel',{'100' '200' '300' '400' '500' '600' '700' '800' '900' '1000'},'FontName', 'Arial','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold','LineWidth',1)

Now, it is important to note that I multiplied W by 100 for scaling as per the V wind. Since the vertical cross-section is along the latitudes, I think only V and W components of wind are needed to get the meridional-vertical wind circulation vector. Right? Or do I have to do something additional to get the desired plot?
For your reference, I attached a sample figure from Zhu et al. (2022).

I wasn't able to figure out how to solve this issue. Can anyone please help me solve this? That will be very helpful for me. Thank you for your time and consideration.
